# Why am I getting very small response times at Client-side?

Tags: http, server, request, client, response

I am trying to measure the response time of a server call (at Client Side) until the reply, but I am getting very small response times (ex 4ms, 5ms etc).
My code (written in java) creates a bunch of requests. 
I can measure the response time with adding the Timestamp before http request with the one after server response.
Reply Timestamp - Call Timestamp = Response Time

```
CallStamp = System.currentTimeMillis(); // Http call stamp
lastHTMLReply = callHTTPServer(lastURL); // Http call
ReplyStamp = System.currentTimeMillis(); // Http reply stamp    
response = ReplyStamp - CallStamp ; // response time
```

Comment: Well, what kind of answer do you expect from us with a vague and generic question like that? That we say "look, in line 54 you initialized that variable in a wrong manner!"?

Comment: You measure a time span not by adding, but by subtracting two points in time. Whether that result is correct depends on whether you computed correctly. If you did depends on your code. You did not post any code, so we cannot help. Sorry.

Comment: Why `python-requests` tag while your code is written in java? Which one is a typo?

Comment: It would help if you showed your code and how you're requesting it. If the http call is async. You can from start timer, send request, then  end timer before you receive the response.